# What is Training step time in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology

In the paper:

> **TensorFlow: A system for large-scale machine learning** (Martín Abadi, Paul Barham, Jianmin Chen, Zhifeng Chen...)

What does the term "step time" or "training step time" mean? Why not just use train time for simplicity?

[image: paper]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In neural network scenario, epoch can be defined as a single forward pass and backward pass of all the training examples. We don't feed in all the neurons into our network at once. Instead, we choose a batch of neurons(mini batch) and feed them in. We process a small subset of training data forwards and backwards. We do this so we can perform stochastic gradient descent, and prevent our network from overfitting. There is difference between individual training step time and total training time. For example, if there are 30 training steps in your network, then total training time = time required to complete all 30 training steps.

[image]

**Please check reference[15] for following table:**

[image]

[**[15] S. Chintala.
convnet-benchmarks,
github.com/soumith/convnet-benchmarks.**](https://github.com/soumith/convnet-benchmarks)

[image]

For AlexNet, caffe training step time is 324 ms.
Total time = forward + backward = 121 + 203